# add new realm version(1.2.0) leading toError:java.util.zip.ZipException

Tags: java, android, realm

I'm using realm database in my android app, before I use realm 1.0.1 and works fine for me but now when I want to set my realm lib to 1.2.0 I'm getting this error message.

```
Error:java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: org/objectweb/asm/AnnotationVisitor.class
at com.android.builder.profile.Recorder$Block.handleException(Recorder.java:54)
at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder$1.record(ThreadRecorder.java:57)
at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder$1.record(ThreadRecorder.java:47)
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask.transform(TransformTask.java:173)
at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:75)
at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:245)
at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:221)
at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$IncrementalTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:232)
at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:210)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:80)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:61)
... 70 more
Error:com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: org/objectweb/asm/AnnotationVisitor.class
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.JarMergingTransform.transform(JarMergingTransform.java:117)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$3.call(TransformTask.java:178)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$3.call(TransformTask.java:174)
    at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder$1.record(ThreadRecorder.java:55)
    ... 79 more
Error:java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: org/objectweb/asm/AnnotationVisitor.class
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.JarMerger.addJar(JarMerger.java:161)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.JarMerger.addJar(JarMerger.java:121)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.JarMergingTransform.transform(JarMergingTransform.java:107)
```

can anyone help me about this?

Comment: Well it says you're including `org/objectweb/asm/AnnotationVisitor` from multiple places, which means you should use `gradle app:dependencies` to show which libraries use both of them; also add your `build.gradle` dependencies if you can

Comment: @max Is this problem solved? thanks

Comment: nope im using older version

Comment: I never learned the dependencies so not much to be done here